# What does Paul mean by asking followers of Christ to give someone over to Satan? 1 Cor. 5:5

Tags: 1-corinthians

There are two dilemmas here for me: Paul, himself, committed murder or approved of it; he was forgiven.  Why could not an adulterer be forgiven?  The second is why would Satan be the one to turn to rather than the Holy Spirit?  The answer I have read posted to a similar question does not really address these two questions, and in fact poses as similar question.

Comment: Paul was not part of Church of Christ but an unbeliever. This man is in the Church but in extreme rebellion whose repentance seems to be impossible; this is why he asks for his excommunication in hope that he might repent in future. He wants to remove such sexual sinners from saints to avoid sinful influence and corruption in church. Satan represents sin; the man is said to be left in his own condition for his own evil works of flesh.

Comment: I mentioned that I had read the previous post -- I believe that I pose a different question that I did not see a response to in that post: Why could this man not be forgiven? Paul was, and he preached Christ crucified for the sins of the world.  Also, and perhaps I missed it, I did not see a specific response in that post about why fhe Church could not seek the Holy Spirit - it seems this would be the first move.  Pray for power to help the sinner.

Comment: Paul also preached or believe Heb10:26-27;6:4-6. The sinner is prayed for HolySpirit and preached truth asked for repentance, fed up of tolerating and forgiving him; and after his deliberate continuous sins he said that let deliver to satan, or live sinfully somewhere else. Its irresponsible to let him live among believers. Paul instructed to excommunicate. Paul preached grace but not licentiousness. [There is sin that leads to death; I do not say that one should pray for that 1Jn5:6]

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if my comment is too trivial to display, but the previous answer specifies sexual sins.  I feel more comfortable with just unrepented, potentially harmful sin as being condemned.